# Fetching rows in a typedef struct array

Tags: c++, sql, c, oracle

My structure is defined like this:

```
typedef struct{
   int v1;
   int v2;
}INFOS_HND;

INFOS_HND hnd_list[100];

EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
   char statement[200];
   int current_row = 0;
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
```

I'm using this statement in pro C/C++.

```
snprintf(statement, sizeof(statement), "select i1, i2, from table_a");
```

And this is my SQL instructions:

```
EXEC SQL PREPARE SEL_INSTR FROM :statement;
EXEC SQL DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SEL_INSTR;
EXEC SQL OPEN MY_CURSOR;
EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND DO break;
while(1){
   EXEC SQL FETCH MY_CURSOR INTO :hnd_list[current_row].v1, :hnd_list[current_row].v2;
   current_row++;
EXEC SQL CLOSE MY_CURSOR;
```

When compiling, these errors are shown:

```
PCC-S-02322, found undefined identifier
Semantic error at line 53, column 10, file my_file:
EXEC SQL FETCH MY_CURSOR INTO :hnd_list[current_row].v1;

PCC-S-02327, struct or struct pointer required
Semantic error at line 53, column 10, file my_file:
EXEC SQL FETCH MY_CURSOR INTO :hnd_list[current_row].v1;

PCC-S-02322, found undefined identifier
Semantic error at line 53, column 30, file my_file:
EXEC SQL FETCH MY_CURSOR INTO :hnd_list[current_row].v2;

PCC-S-02327, struct or struct pointer required
Semantic error at line 53, column 30, file my_file:
EXEC SQL FETCH MY_CURSOR INTO :hnd_list[current_row].v2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The type and variable definitions are declared outside the PRO*C/C++ DECLARE block. So the precompiler can't resolve the declaration. Try to move them inside the block, as follows:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;

typedef struct{
   int v1;
   int v2;
}INFOS_HND;

INFOS_HND hnd_list[100];

char statement[200];
int current_row = 0;

EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
```